# SoundPool to MediaPlayer in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

I unfortunately did not realize that SoundPool only will play ~5 seconds of any file, and I am trying to play files that are larger than that but already did most of the code with SoundPool. So I am wondering how to easily change my code from using SoundPool to MediaPlayer? My main concern is that with SoundPool I was using all the files in an asset sub-file called sample_music, and it seems that with MediaPlayer you can't do that. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Here are my two main files with SoundPool:

```
public class Featured {
private static final String TAG = "Featured";
private static final String MUSIC_FOLDER = "sample_music";
private static final int MAX_SONGS = 1; //One song can be played at a time
private AssetManager mAssets;
private List<Song> mSongs = new ArrayList<>();
private SoundPool mSoundPool;

public Featured(Context context) {
    mAssets = context.getAssets();
    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(MAX_SONGS, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    loadFeatured();
}

public void play(Song song) {
    Integer songId = song.getSongId();
    if (songId == null) { return; } //No song
    mSoundPool.play(songId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
}

private void loadFeatured() {
    String[] songTitles;
    try {
        songTitles = mAssets.list(MUSIC_FOLDER);
        Log.i(TAG, "Found " + songTitles.length + " songs");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not list assets", ioe);
        return;
    }

    //Build a list of songs
    for (String filename : songTitles){
        try {
            String assetPath = MUSIC_FOLDER + "/" + filename;
            Song song = new Song(assetPath);
            load(song);
            mSongs.add(song);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not load song " + filename, ioe);
        }
    }
}

//Load songs
public void load(Song song)throws IOException {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = mAssets.openFd(song.getAssetPath());
    int songId = mSoundPool.load(afd, 1); //load for later playback
    song.setSongId(songId);
}

public List<Song> getSongs() {
    return mSongs;
}
}
```

And the other file:

```
public class FeaturedFragment extends Fragment {
private Featured mFeatured;

public static FeaturedFragment newInstance() {
    return new FeaturedFragment();
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mFeatured = new Featured(getActivity());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Load recycler view of featured songs
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_featured, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_featured_recycler_view);
    //set 3 songs per row
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new SoundAdapter(mFeatured.getSongs()));
    return view;
}

private class SoundHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Button mButton;
    private Song mSong;

    public SoundHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_sound, container, false));
        mButton = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_sound_button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void bindSong(Song song) {
        mSong = song;
        mButton.setText(mSong.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mFeatured.play(mSong);
    }
}
private class SoundAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SoundHolder> {
    private List<Song> mSongs;
    public SoundAdapter(List<Song> songs) {
        mSongs = songs;
    }

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public SoundHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        return new SoundHolder(inflater, parent);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SoundHolder soundHolder, int position) {
        Song song = mSongs.get(position);
        soundHolder.bindSong(song);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSongs.size();
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

With SoundPool you would indeed call the load() method and it would assign an id per audio file you wish to play later on. With MediaPlayer you would simply add the absolute paths in a list. Whenever you wish to play a song. Just select a song from your list, pass it to the static create() method of the MediaPlayer and call the start() method to start playing the audio file. Here's an example

```
   public void PlaySong(Context context, string songToPlay) {

   MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context,Uri.parse(songToPlay));

   if (player != null) {
       player.start() 
   }
}
```

That's it. Hope that helps you in your transition to using MediaPlayer.